# GeckoFx disable window.print of html

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, geckofx

I use GeckoFx to capture an image of a web page.
The problem is that this web page has a script:

```
<script language = "JavaScript">
window.print (); window.close ();
</ script>
```

The above script opens a print dialog box and requires interactive user input to continue.

**Question**: How do I automate the process - for example say by stopping the dialog from opening.

Is there a way to disable the native javascript printing method (`window.print`)?

I already tried to inject a script into the html header:

```
window.print = function () {}
```

But this does not work. it inserts the script but the dialog box keeps showing up. (I do it in the `DocumentCompleted` event).

I found how to disable `window.alert` using `PromptServiceCreator`, but I can not disable `window.print`

I do not care about `window.close` because it does not run (firefox does not run it).

Comment: Why the vba tag please?

Comment: you could try setting GeckoPreference "print.always_print_silent" to true.

Comment: If I use print.always_print_silent, the dialog box disappears but sends the printer to print by default
that's not what I'm looking for, I need to disable the impression.

Comment: A way that certainly works is to modify GeckoFx source directly, see the Print() method in GeckoWindow.cs.